# Layout in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm making a wheel of fortune type game in react native and have got to the point where making the UI is a little frustrated

[image: blob]

The image above is basically how the UI should look. I want to have the wheel in the middle and then the info blobs to randomly appear around the wheel. I've used justify content and align items to center the wheel, however its the random placing of these blobs and the fact that I don't want them to overlap any of the remaining UI elements that's the problem.

I thought maybe about implementing some kind of grid system, but not sure how to go about this or even if this is the correct way to do something like this

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you include that code in the question?

Comment: At the moment, I only have the wheel in place, by setting the style prop of the parent to

style= {{flex:1, justiftContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}

I thought about the possibility of setting each blob to have an absolute position, and then set the left property to:  Math.random() x SCREEN_WIDTH and top prop to: Math.random() x SCREEN_HEIGHT. However I'm not sure how to esure that I don't overlap the wheel. I would need to account for the area the wheel takes up

Comment: This question is quite broad, but I think what you're really asking is "How do I select a random point on a rectangle with a round hole in it?". Is this accurate?

Comment: @Kraylog that's pretty much what I'm asking. The problem I've got is how I ensure that if there's multiple components on the screen, that they don't overlap each other

Answer (score 0):

If the number of "blobs" is small, then a simple algorithm can get pretty decent results:

```
1. Select random point within the containing square
2. Check if point overlaps the circle or any other blob
3. If overlap, goto 1.
4. repeat until n blobs.
```

To check if two circles overlap, you just need to measure the distance between their centers and subtract their radii.

```
isOverlapping = sqrt(pow(x2 - x1, 2) + pow(y2 - y1, 2)) - (r1 + r2) < 0
```